# make emacs semantic auto complete tip "always on"

Tags: emacs, autocomplete, cedet, emacs-semantic

I have just installed cedet (CVS version) and I am now playing with in emacs and my C++ source code.

Regarding the auto complete, I can invoke the tool tip and the menu from their semantic-ia-complete-* commands.

Does anyone know how I can make the auto complete tip appear automatically without my having to invoke a command `(semantic-ia-complete-tip)`? Is this even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [CEDET website](http://cedet.sourceforge.net/intellisense.shtml):

> **Automatically starting inline completion in idle time**
>
> ```
> M-x global-semantic-idle-completions-mode
> ```
>
> This is a minor mode which runs
>   semantic-complete-analyze-inline-idle
>   during idle time. Instead of trying to
>   complete the symbol immediately, it
>   will just display the possible
>   completions, and underline the current
>   symbol the cursor is on.

In practice this means that the possible completions will appear whenever you stop typing and the cursor is under a symbol where completions are possible.

To use it, just put

```
(global-semantic-idle-completions-mode)
```

to your .emacs after loading the CEDET.

Comment: I have already tried that. I actually invoke that mode from within emacs for now (using M-x). But with this mode active, the suggestion that would have been at the top of the tooltip, or the completions menu, is displayed on the line itself and no tooltip nor menuy is shown.

Comment: Using the inline completion myself, I didn't notive that this idle mode only uses inline completion, that's a pity. To the best of my knowledge, the current CEDET does not have functionality you want.

Comment: To change the completion style, you need to customize the variable semantic-complete-inline-analyzer-idle-displayor-class, and choose one of the other displayor types.

Many folks found the popup annoying, so an alternate default was presented.